# react-native facebook account kit

Tags: react-native, account-kit

Just wondering if anyone have done this before.

I have a react-native app that uses a phone number to authenticate. So, decided to go with Account kit. My question is, can we do our own UI and still able to perform the Account kit to send sms instead of using the UI that is popup from Account kit. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think we can have our own UI for this, its not available in Android or iOS, so don't think its possible in RN.  Found this repo https://github.com/underscopeio/react-native-facebook-account-kit if its helpful. If you have found any other way do share it here please. Thanks.

Comment: I found we can use Firebase phone number login with custom ui - https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth